# Failed to install package Beautiful Soup. Error Message is "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have installed Python 3.5 on my Windows 8 Computer. I have also installed Pycharm Community Version 5.0.4. I am not able to install BeautifulSoup Module through Settings Option in Pycharm. I am getting the following error in Pycharm:

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Kashyap\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\BeautifulSoup\setup.py", line 22
      print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                    ^
  SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

  ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Kashyap\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging0.tmp\BeautifulSoup
```

Path of installed folder of Python is 3.5.1 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are trying to install BeautifulSoup 3, which is not Python 3 compatible. As the Pycharm error window explains:

> Make sure you use a version of Python supported by this package. Currently you are using Python 3.5.

However, you want to install BeautifulSoup *4* instead; the project name for that series has changed to [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). BeautifulSoup 4 has been out for a few years now and supports Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

Using Anaconda with the more current `BeautifulSoup4` is the easiest.

```
conda install BeautifulSoup4
```

or

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Comment: `(base) user@system:~$ conda install BeautifulSoup4`


`Solving environment: done`



`# All requested packages already installed.`

still throws the same error.. :( in pycharm and in normal terminal interpreter

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```